# Can't change Java version

Tags: java, bashrc

I had Java 11, then decided to change to Java 8. I uninstalled 11 and installed 8.
Then have added these lines into `~/.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
    export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Executed `source ~/.bashrc`.
`javac -version` gives 8, but `java -version` still shows 11.
I tried to use `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` and set it to 8, but still...

Comment: AFAIK `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` sets the JDK version; to set the JRE version, you need `sudo update-alternatives --config java`